# During a chef run how does node differ from node.default?

Tags: chef-infra, configuration-management

I've noticed that attributes in environments do not get applied if I use `node.default` in cookbooks (instead the cookbook attributes get applied). But, the attributes changed in environments get applied if I use `node` instead; why? I thought `node` and `node.default` are one and the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node attribute precedence can be confusing. The document does help, once you read it a couple of times

https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html

My advice is as follows:

1. Set default attributes in an attributes file within your cookbook. Don't confuse yourself by doing this within recipes as well.
2. Override the attributes of other cookbooks by setting "normal" attributes and again do this in an attributes file within your cookbook
3. At runtime using Environment or Role attributes to override all attributes set within cookbooks.
4. Never edit the node attributes directly on the chef server. There is no transactional locking, which means your update could be lost if a chef client is running at the same time....

The objective here is consistency

Comment: @josten Oh, apologies. Yes the syntax was changed in Chef 11. The following link gives more details: https://www.chef.io/blog/2013/02/05/chef-11-in-depth-attributes-changes/. In short "node[a]" is used to read the existing value saved within the Chef node object and "node.default[a]" is used to set the value.

Answer (score 3):

`node` gives you a view into the entire node object.  `node.default` only tells you what values were set at the `default` level.  As a result, you should NEVER read from `node.default` as you would be explicitly ignoring all higher precedent levels.  ie, your `overrides` would not count.  `node.default` exists to allow you to SET default values on the node.